# Laravel 4 - Route not defined

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've created my route:

```
Route::get('fichas/orden/{id}', 'FichaController@orden');
```

My Controller:

```
public function orden($id)
{
    return $id;
}
```

And I have this in my View:

```
{{ link_to_route('fichas.orden', 'Guardar orden', array($ficha->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
```

And I don't know why I'm having this error. I have been using this kind of routes and views all the time and I haven't got any problem until now. Does anybody know why it doesn't work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link to a named route, you have to define the route as follows:

```
Route::get('fichas/orden/{id}', array('as'=>'fichas.orden', 'uses'=>'FichaController@orden'));
```